# Alter wp_post table vs. post_meta performance/speed

Tags: mysql, performance, core-modifications

I'm searching for the most efficient way to link a post to multiple users.

By default each post in `wp_post` has a `post_author` column, which is linked to the corresponding user ID in `wp_users`.

Assume I there are the following custom user roles

- custom_supervisor
- custom_author
- custom_editor

The post is created by the supervisor who then assigned a author and an editor.
Each post has to be assigned to one user of each role mentioned above.

### Option A

Use the supervisor as `post_author` and add the user IDs of the author and editor with  `add_post_meta()` with unique meta_keys like `_custom_author` and `_custom_editor`.

This would be the standard wordpress way of accomplishing task.

### Option B

Alter the `wp_post` table, add two columns like `post_supervisor` and `post_editor` and use `post_author` for the custom author role. Modify worpdress to add the right values when creating a post. E.g. custom metaboxes passing predefined values for the new columns.
Main problem with this solution would be the customization regarding backup etc.

### Option C

Create new many-to-one relation table to link supervisors,authors and editors to newly created post ID. Table contains only mapping information and every column is indexed for maximum speed. Plugin or theme functionality has to implement new queries.

### Problem

Each user of each custom user role will query for posts assigned to it... very, very often.
By using "Option A" every user role except the supervisors (assigned to `post_author`) will have to query the `post_meta` table in order to receive the assigned posts.

If my assumption is correct I would face serious performance issues when using constantly querying the `post_meta` table for specific values(eg `WHERE _custom_editor = 2`) since wordpress is not originally designed for this. (Normal behavior would be to query post_meta after one or multiple post IDs are received, not the other way round).
See: [What is an efficient way to query based on post_meta?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69734/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-query-based-on-post-meta)

Any suggestions on the performance, comparing the three options or additional new methods for maximum efficiency and speed?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Option B is a non-starter in my opinion. Have you considered leveraging Co-authors Plus in some way?

Comment: I feel like modifying the `wp_post` table is a bad idea incase WordPress eventually sends out a database update. Better off creating your own table. If it's just giving specific users access to specific posts, why not save the `post_id`'s as [`user_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) then you could query off of those specific post IDs (post__in) which I imagine is marginally faster. IMO don't over optimize just yet, build it out first then find the bottlenecks. Odds are no matter what your solution is the gained speed will be unnoticeable.

Comment: @vancoder: I looked at coauthors before posting just to for a base to start. The plugin just stores an array of authors with `wp_set_post_terms` but that's a huge advantage over using `post_meta` 
@Howdy_McGee: that's a valid concern! will use a separate table. It's not about access, more like listing all posts which are assigned constantly and checking for new posts by each user so querying for specific IDs is not an option.

Thank you both for your comments!